# Application of "Riesz Interpolation" for $L^p$-Norm of a Fourier-Transformed Function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

I am asking this question to try to decipher notes given by my professor.

We have a function, $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $, and we are trying to bound its $L^p$-Norm, where $p>2$. This function has a nice Fourier Transform, so we would like to bound the norm of $f$ by the norm of $\mathcal{F}[f] = \hat{f}$ somehow.

According to my professor's scrawlings, we can say that, for $p>2$,

$ ||f||_{p} \leq C ||\hat{f}||_{\frac{p}{p-1}} $, by "Riesz Interpolation".

I am unfortunately not able to figure what he means by this, or how this can be proven. He writes that it somehow comes from the fact that the $L^\infty$- and $L^2$-norms can be bounded in the following ways:

$||f||_{\infty} \leq C ||\hat{f}||_{1}, \ \ ||f||_{2} = ||\hat{f}||_{2}$.

I understand these two facts well enough, but am not seeing how we get the more general result above.

Comment: In your question, haven't you mixed up $f$ and $\hat{f}$ quite a number of times?

Comment: @Brozovic They are in the reverse order from what you usually find, yes, but I believe they still hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your professor is referring to the [Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Thorin_theorem). It basically says that if a linear operator $T$ is bounded as a map $L^{p_1}\to L^{q_1}$ and also as a map $L^{p_2}\to L^{q_2}$, then it is also bounded as a map $L^{p_\theta}\to L^{q_\theta}$ for
$$
\frac{1}{p_\theta} = \frac{\theta}{p_1} + \frac{1-\theta}{p_2}, \frac{1}{q_\theta} = \frac{\theta}{q_1} + \frac{1-\theta}{q_2}, ~\theta\in[0,1].
$$
The full statement also gives you a bound on the operator norm. The idea is to apply this in the specific case that $T$ is the Fourier transform, using the two endpoint bounds you have already stated.

The resulting estimate is called the [Hausdorff-Young inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff%E2%80%93Young_inequality).

Comment: Oh my God, that makes so much sense now haha. Yes, I'm actually familiar with this result. Just couldn't make the association in my head without the proper name written in front of me haha. Thank you very much!